# How can I get the type of the parameters of an overridden method in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, typing, strong-typing

I want to make a method in a subclass B typesafe without importing a private interface that is being used for the args.

```
// file A.ts
class A<T> {
    hello(name: PrivateInterface) {
         console.log("Hello", name);
    }
}

// file B.ts
class B extends A<Foo> {
    hello(
        ...args // How to type this without PrivateInterface?
    ) {
         super(...args);
    }
}
```

I can get the ReturnType of a method using `Parameters<this["hello"]>` and I cannot do the same for the same using the same with the superclass `Parameters<super["hello"]>`.

Comment: how about `<Parameters<A<Foo>["hello"]>`?